# Pytorch Adam optimizer's awkward behavior? better with restart?

Tags: optimization, deep-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent

I'm trying to train a CNN text classifier with Pytorch. I'm using the Adam optimizer like this.

`optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(CNN_Text.parameters(), lr=args.lr)`

I figured out that the optimizer converges really fast, and then it keeps on slowly dropping on accuracy. (the validation loss decreases a lot in 1-2 minutes, then it keeps on increasing slowly)

So, I implemented learning-rate decay,

`If curr_loss > val_loss:
   prev_lr = param_group['lr']
   param_group['lr'] = prev_lr/10`

I found out that it didn't really help a lot. But if I manually save the model, load it, and run the training with decreased learning rate, it really gets way better performance!

This gets me in hard time because I need to keep on watching the gradient descent and manually change the options. I tried SGD and other optimizers because I thought this was Adam's problem, but I couldn't find out a good way.

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 2):

What is `param_group`? With that code snippet it looks like a variable not associated with the optimizer in any way. What you need to modify is the `'lr'` entry of each element of `optimizer.param_groups`, which is what `ADAM` actually looks at.

Either way, unless you have a good reason to hand-roll it yourself, I suggest you use the [LR scheduler](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/optim.html#torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau) provided with PyTorch. And if you do need to reimplement it, check out its [code](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.html#ReduceLROnPlateau) and take inspiration from there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Adam has additional internal parameters (cumulative averages of gradients, etc.) that need also to be reset.

For this reason, you have a better chance deleting the instantiating the optimiser with a lower learning rate.

At least that worked for me.